# Why does MSVC refuse to compile `static_assert(std::size(arr) < N)` when [array] `arr` declared thread local?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Attempting to compile some `example.cpp` containing the following:

```cpp
#include <array>

void test() {
    thread_local int arr[10];
    static_assert(std::size(arr) < 100);
}
```

MSVC 19.35.32215 tells me:

> ```
> 1>example.cpp(5,34): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
> 1>example.cpp(5,29): message : failure was caused by non-constant arguments or reference to a non-constant symbol
> 1>example.cpp(5,29): message : see usage of 'arr'
> ```

The same snippet not containing the `thread_local` specifier, compiles just fine.

For reference, this is Visual C++ where I have experimented with trying to enforce standard compliance (`/std:c++20`), and `/sdl` is used as well -- these changes do not eliminate the compilation error. Also, http://godbolt.org gives me the same error when using MSVC "latest", but, more importantly, latest Clang, for instance, compiles the otherwise problematic snippet just fine.

I don't know how to get the full `cl` command line as used by the IDE when building my solution through the Visual Studio 2022 GUI I am using, but I *do* get the same compilation error if I drop to a VS developer command prompt environment and invoke `cl` directly: `cl /c example.cpp` (with or without `/std:c++20`) gets me the same error, basically:

> ```
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.35.32215 for x86
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> example.cpp
> example.cpp(5): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
> example.cpp(5): note: failure was caused by non-constant arguments or reference to a non-constant symbol
> example.cpp(5): note: see usage of 'arr'
> ```

I fail to see why thread-local storage for `arr` should prevent the compiler from deducing its size given the declaration, and subsequently perform `static_assert` as expected? Am I missing some subtle property of modern C++ here?

Comment: Did you mean to assert `sizeof(arr)`??

Comment: No, I did not. Why do you ask? `sizeof(arr)` would give me amount of `char` elements the array would span (please correct if my understanding is wrong), while what I am after is the _number of elements_ the array contains, in this case 10 (vs. 40 `char` objects it spans). The numbers `10` and `100` in the snippet are just examples, but the important thing in this context is that both are literals.

Comment: `std::size` is a regular template function. `thread_local` variables are not `constexpr` thus even `constexpr` function would evaluate regularly, at runtime. Meaning it cannot be called inside `static_assert`

Comment: @ALX23z What makes you say that? Here it is a `constexpr` and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size also clearly declares it such? There is also the fact that Clang compiles the snippet just fine (although it must be mentioned it may or may not be standards compliant with regard to that)?

Comment: Can the person voting to close this as "caused by a typo", please retract their vote? This is a legitimate situation, as described, and I have verified this in several ways. There are no "typos" here. @πάνταῥεῖ?

Comment: The input is not `constexpr`. Function declared `constexpr` can be evaluates at either compile-time or runtime. Your input  `arr` is not declared `constexpr` so it should be evaluated at runtime. Not sure what allows the compilers to bypass the restriction.

Comment: @ALX23z "_The input is not constexpr_": That's only relevant if an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to it (or it is a variable of reference type, until a recent DR).

Comment: File a VS feedback bug on this please.

Comment: @ALX23z The input does not have to be explicitly declared a `constexpr` -- `std::size` is well known to be able to operate on arrays, possible implementation conforming to standard declaration would be `template <class T, std::size_t N> constexpr std::size_t size(const T (&array)[N]) noexcept { return N; }` allowing it to be passed an array, regardless of the presence of `thread_local` specifier.

Comment: fyi this compiles `static_assert( sizeof(arr) < 100 );` with MSVC.

Comment: fyi2 MSVC's [`std::size`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/xutility#L1714) on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a MSVC bug. The code is fine and should compile. The storage duration of `arr` should be irrelevant. As suggested in the comments under the question, you should report it.

Just referencing a non-`constexpr` variable of object type doesn't cause an expression to not be a (core) constant expression and you are neither applying an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `arr` or its subobjects, nor are you producing a pointer or lvalue to it or any of its subobjects as a result of the constant expression. The result of `std::size(arr)` is only dependent on its (deduced) template argument.

Comment: Thank you, I've reported it: http://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/use-of-std::sizearr-as-part-of-argum/10314331